# How can I make an asynchronous API call in Java (Dropwizard framework) to update Couchbase records?

Tags: java, couchbase, dropwizard, couchbase-java-api

I have to update multiple records in Couchbase database. With some research I got to know that to do this I have to make an asynchronous call to database with batching. I can't update all the records in one go, so for this I have to make database call in batches and it should be asynchronous call. But I don't know How I can achieve this? Can anyone help me with this? or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You can use OkHttp.

Comment: By "help me with this" do you mean "write my code for me" ;-P

If you show what you've tried, what you expected it to do, and how it failed, I think it would make it much more probable that people would be able to help you.

Comment: Hi Vikram. Start with the Couchbase Java SDK documentation on the [async/reactive APIs](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/current/howtos/concurrent-async-apis.html). Then take a look at this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66388023/how-to-perform-batch-insertions-in-couchbase-with-latest-java-sdk-3-1-2